# How to configure Sustainsys.Saml2 http module to protect the whole web app?

Tags: httpmodule, sustainsys-saml2

Is it possible to configure Sustainsys.Saml2 HTTP module to protect the whole web app behind it?

I.e. to configure it in the way that the HTTP module will automatically force the user to login if the request is not authenticated.

The goal is to protect the web app without any modification to the app itself.

I am able to setup the SAML2 http module and the required Session Authentication Module but how to configure the module to automatically invoke the login URL when the request is not authenticated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Use authorization rules in web.config.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right direction. I have used the following settings:

`<system.web>
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Saml2/SignIn?idp=***" timeout="2880"/>
   </authentication>
   <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
   </authorization>
</system.web>`

And it seems to work fine.